# DB2 creating three columns Years/Quarters/weeks from timestamp

Tags: db2

I been searching for way to separate timestamp  into three columns years show the year only and another column show in which quarter and third column to show in which week of the quarter week 1-week 12

not sure which function would allow me to do as such anyone got through that?

Thanks!!

Comment: There are literally functions named `YEAR`, and `QUARTER`.  There's a `WEEK` function that returns a number between 1-54 (you could divide by `QUARTER`, but I hope it's obvious that this will return **13**  or **14** weeks).  If you're trying to _query_ based on this information (ie, `WHERE YEAR(timestampColumn) = 2014`), or perform grouping, this will prevent you from using indices - you'd be better off using a Calendar Table with the requisite columns pre-computed (which is necessary if your fiscal year doesn't match the ISO calendar year).  What do you plan to do with this information?

Comment: I just want to create three columns that show the year alone and quarter and week from timestamp table not sure what to type in the query to make this possible lets say we making view that will have timestamp and those three columns what should be the syntax to make it right and lets say table name is KPP  and columns years and quarters and weeks will be created in this view by taking from time stamp column i don't want to add speicific year in the where i want it to take what year from time stamp whatever it is same to Quarter and weeks

Comment: Well... first problem: There are a minimum of `52` weeks in a year, not 48 (so 13 weeks per quarter).  When does week 1 start?  The first day of the year, or on a specific day of the week?  What have you tried already?  SO is not a place for us to do your work for you, it's for when you've done what you can, and are stuck.  So what have you tried?  What about your current efforts isn't working?

Comment: first week of quarter one first day of the year yes 
 sorry if i didn't explain much  i have tried the following :
I separated the time stamp to year and quarter and week using this query

select EVENTTIMESTAMP, Year (EVENTTIMESTAMP), QUARTER (EVENTTIMESTAMP), Week (EVENTTIMESTAMP) from KAP.COGNOS

Comment: there only two things i was trying to enhance in it 1- the weeks returns a number between 1-54, I want it to be return 13 or 14 weeks as weeks of Quarters i tried to put the Week function after it to devide / 4 as 4 quarters but the results not right 

2- to add word before the number of Quarter 'Quarter' and then it's number, and so to the weeks to show word 'Week' then the number when i add the word 'Week' before function week so it show as word week and then it's number it give me error should it be written in specific way 

Many Thanks!!